# initiate widgetUserBox in shiny in "collapsed" status

Tags: shiny

I'm using widgetuserBox in shiny but the default status is collapsed = FALSE. Is there a way to have the box closed when you start the app?

Comment: any suggestion about this question?

Comment: Anybody has suggestion regarding this? This should have been a simple feature in the code similar to what we can do with box() or boxPlus(). I'm not sure why it hasn't been implemented. Any suggestion is appreciated.